# FilterConfig in visual studio 2015

Tags: asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to migrate my asp.net mvc web api project to visual studio 2015 preview version.

I am not finding a way to adopt the FilterConfig.cs code on visual studio 2015 since the 2015 version doesn't going to support global.asax, web.config.

So where i can put my filterconfig, areaconfig.

Comment: In ASP.NET MVC 6 you use the `Startup` class: http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/aspnet-vnext/create-a-web-api-with-mvc-6

Comment: what is that you are trying to do?

Comment: Try start here: http://aspnet.readthedocs.org/en/latest/migrating/migratingconfig/migratingconfig.html

Answer (score 2):

You need to register your filters in the StartUp class, inside the ConfigureServices method:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Add MVC services to the services container.
        services.AddMvc().Configure<MvcOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.Filters.Add(typeof (MyGlobalFilterAttribute));
        });
    }
```